# I can't find the GlobalNavigation WebPart

Tags: web-part, my-site, delegate-control

I wan't to modify the MySite GlobalNavigation WebPart to customize the title in the top left corner. I can find there is a delegate control in the master page but I can't find this control anywhere...
Thank for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate Controls are activated by FEATURES. So you need to find a FEATURE that contains the definition of Delegate Cotrol.

And for you its the feature ‘My Site Navigation’ which is located in {SharePointRoot}\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\MySiteNavigation\Feature.xml.

If you observe the element file of that FEATURE, you will see that the top navigation corresponds to ~/_controltemplates/mysitetopnavigation.ascx located in CONTROLTEMPLATES directory of SharePoint root.

The beauty of delegate controls (plenty of examples if you type "Sharepoint delegate control" in search engine) is that you can OTB control with your own control on activation of your custom FEATURE. This excellent series talk about customizing the top nav in my sites. Check it out: http://weshackett.com/2011/02/sp2010-mysites-part-three-branding/

Comment: Thank you very much. In MySiteTopNavigation.ascx I think the title I want to modify is defined by 
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
    <SPSWC:MySiteLink ID="mysitelink" runat="server"/>
</div>
but the TagPrefix SPSWC points on the assembly "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal". Does it mean I can't modify the title easily ?

Comment: My mistake, I just changed the SPSWC balise by a simple a balise and it's ok ;) Thank you again

Comment: Looks like that is coming from a resource file. You can replace with your own ascx file as the article describes and change to however you want it.